# how to expire partitions of existing partitioned tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a copy of the production dataset in BigQuery to the testing environment and use it to simulate the pipeline processing with new changes.

However, the production dataset is huge. so I usually want to only keep its most recent data for testing.

To do that, I would like to truncate all partitioned data that is older than 30 days in my dataset.

I tried setting partition expiration at the dataset level. it doesn't work.

So how could I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests about this and confirmed that.

When you set a default partition expiration at the dataset level. It only applies to the new tables.
for the existing partitioned tables, you need to set the partition at individual table level to expire its partitions.
For example:

```
 ALTER TABLE `gcp_A.dataset_1.measurements`
 SET OPTIONS (
   -- Sets partition expiration to 30 days
   partition_expiration_days=30
 ); 

select min(stamp) from `gcp_A.dataset_1.measurements`
-- [result] 
-- 2021-06-15 00:00:00 UTC
```